# Provisioning target computer for driver deployment results in errors installing driver test framework

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, wdk

I’ve tried reprovisioning the computer multiple times, have confirmed that secure boot is disabled, the host and target can ping each other, and the WDK remote setup appears to have run properly. Below is the error log I received on provisioning the target most recently.

```
Copying required files
    Task "Copying required files" completed successfully
Configuring WDK Remote User Account
    Task "Configuring WDK Remote User Account" completed successfully
Installing .NET Framework (possible reboot)
    Task "Installing .NET Framework (possible reboot)" completed successfully
Installing VC Redist (x64)
    Task "Installing VC Redist (x64)" completed successfully
Installing test automation (x86)
    Task "Installing test automation (x86)" completed successfully
Installing test automation (x64)
    Task "Installing test automation (x64)" completed successfully
Installing debuggers (x86)
    Task "Installing debuggers (x86)" completed successfully
Installing debuggers (x64)
    Task "Installing debuggers (x64)" completed successfully
Installing driver test framework
    ERROR: Task "Installing driver test framework" failed to complete successfully. Look at the logs in the driver test group explorer for more details on the failure.
Registering logging components
    Task "Registering logging components" completed successfully
Installing TAEF service
    Task "Installing TAEF service" completed successfully
Configuring TAEF test service to start automatically
    Task "Configuring TAEF test service to start automatically" completed successfully
Configuring kernel debugger settings (possible reboot)
    Task "Configuring kernel debugger settings (possible reboot)" completed successfully
Configuring computer settings (possible reboot)
    Task "Configuring computer settings (possible reboot)" was aborted because an error occured on the target machine during execution.

An error occurred on the target machine while querying for the status of a remote task.
Error code: 32
Error message: Error while polling TAEF task status
Creating system restore point
    Task "Creating system restore point" completed successfully
Computer configuration log file://C:/Users/TailSPIN/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/WDKTestInfrastructure/ProvisioningLogs/Driver%20Test%20Computer%20Configuration%2020220512110132849.log
Failed installing components
```

Attempting to deploy with install at this stage is unsuccessful and produces the errors below. I believe these errors are related to the failed install of testing frameworks.

````
Driver Deployment Task Failed: Driver Preparation
Driver Deployment Task Failed: Default Driver Package Installation Task
Driver Deployment Task Failed: Driver Post Install Actions ```
````